# Histogram of character occurrences in a sentence

Tags: c

**The problem:**

Design a word and character counter and display a histogram of particular characters.

The histogram may use any character to denote a single instance of a particular letter, such as an `X`, and should print the number of instances for that letter at the end of the line.  Only print the results for characters that have one or more occurrences in the entered sentence.  Your program must treat lower case and upper case of the same letter as separate characters.

Below is an example of what a histogram might look like for the sentence: `i_Looooove__eps_II`

```
Word total: 4
Character total: 18
Character total omitting underscore: 14

e: XX (2)
i: X (1)
o: XXXXX (5)
p: X (1)
s: X (1)
v: X (1)
I: XX (2)
L: X (1)
_: XXXX (4)
```

**Here is what I have so far:**

```
void histogram(char array3[]){
    char alphabet[25] = {0};
    int count;
    char *locate;
    int i;
    int j;

    for(i=0; array3[i] != '\0'; i++){
        array3[i] = tolower(array3[i]);
    }
    count = 0;
    for(i = 0; i <= 25; i++){
        locate = &array3[i];
        while(locate = strchr(locate, 'a' + i)){
            ++count;
            locate++;
        }
        alphabet[i] = count;
    }
    printf("\nThe number of occurrences of each letter is: \n");

    for(i = 0; i <= 25;i++){
        printf("%c:%3d\n", 'a' + i, alphabet[i]);
    }
    return;
}
```

**Something is not working as I expect:**

The output of the histogram is all ones instead of the number of occurrences of each character.

Comment: I am extremely disappointed that you have tried to cover up the fact that you asked for and received help on this problem by trashing the question content and attempting to vandalise my answer.  Obviously it's a homework assignment.  Apart from being ungracious, you have also been sneaky and dishonest.  I will flag this for the moderators.  Don't expect future help from me.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a good start:

```
locate = &array3[i];
```

You are examining each `i`th letter of the alphabet (case-insensitive), and searching for that letter beginning at the `i`th position in your input string.  This is just wrong.  You also should reset `count` each time through the loop.

Your approach is a little backwards compared to the conventional way.  Instead of searching the entire string for every possible character, you should simply count those characters that you encounter.  This should be roughly what you want:

```
int counts[256] = {0};

int num_words = 0;         // Total number of words
int num_chars = 0;         // Total number of characters (including underscores)
int num_underscores = 0;   // Total number of underscores
int in_word = 0;           // Are we currently inside a word?

for( int i = 0; str[i] != 0; i++ )
{
    if( isalpha(str[i]) )
    {
        counts[str[i]]++;
        num_chars++;

        if( !in_word ) {
            in_word = 1;
            num_words++;
        }
    }
    else if( str[i] == '_' )
    {
        counts[str[i]]++;
        num_underscores++;
        in_word = 0;
    }
    else {
        // Unhandled character.  Treat as word-break?
        in_word = 0;
    }      
}
```

You can work out the rest from here.

**[edit]** I guess not...

```
printf( "Word total: %d\n", num_words );
printf( "Character total: %d\n", num_chars );
printf( "Character total omitting underscore: %d\n", num_chars - num_underscores );

for( int i = 0; i < 256; i++ )  // Yes, this loop range is excessive...
{
    if( counts[i] == 0 ) continue;
    printf( "%c: ", (char)i );
    for( int x = 0; x < counts[i]; x++ ) fputc('X', stdout);
    printf( " (%d)\n", counts[i] );
}
```

If you're still confused about it, here is the code distilled to show purely character frequency counts:

```
int counts[256] = {0};

for( int i = 0; str[i] != 0; i++ )
{
    counts[str[i]]++;
}
```

Note that there is an array position for every possible character value.  For each character in the string, you just increment its count.  You're only really interested in `counts['a']`, `counts['b']` *etc* (and similarly for uppercase and the underscore).  But if your input is well-behaved, then this is fine because all the other character counts will remain zero.

Answer (score 0):

This here is causing issues

```
for(i = 0; i <= 25; i++)
```

i goes from 0..25 i.e. 26 characters but your array is only dimensioned for 25 characters:

```
char alphabet[25] = {0};
```

your loop should be

```
for(i = 0; i < 25; i++)
```